# TFS code review comments syntax

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I type `[SomeText](SomeOtherText)` in a comment in a review in TFS, the text in round brackets disappears and the one in square gets highlighted.

Is there a way to escape it? What can I use it for? Is there documentation somewhere?

EDIT: As it has been suggested by @Chamberlain, the link syntax is Markdown, but yet no link seems to work, what kind of links can I use?

Answer (score 1):

This is using [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) language. It's similar to *html* language. `[]()` this means **links**.

A example as below:

```
http://github.com - automatic!
[GitHub](http://github.com)
```

More detailed documentation, you can refer to the link from GitHub  [Mastering Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/)

Comment: How is this connected with my question?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, have updated my answer. The syntax are using Markdown.

Comment: I have tried to copy the markdown from the Wikipedia page but none of them (apart from the link) seem to work. Is it using a restricted version just for links? Also, links don't seem to work, I always get: "The system cannot find the file specified"